# PHP foreach loop takes array element not in order

Tags: php

I have an array I am building like this:

```
$acids = array();
foreach ($sortedArray as $h)
{
 $acids[] = $h['account_id'];
}
$uniqueAids = array_unique($acids);
```

When I then run through that array to output it, I expect this:

```
Array
(
 [0] => 353
 [1] => 176
 [2] => 9
)
```

but i get this :

```
Array
(
 [0] => 353
 [1] => 176
 [4] => 9
)
```

Comment: You can sort arrays like this;

    sort($acids);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because values 2 and 3 contain the values 353 or 176. You can use array_values to resort the keys.

```
$uniqueAids = array_values(array_unique($acids));
```

Comment: @SalaUddin i am new  in stackoverflow, how i can mark is expected answer

Comment: @sandy at the bottom of number of vote you have see a tick mark. so click on this tick mark

Answer (score 3):

Keys are preserved when you use `array_unique()`. So all you need to do is

```
$uniqueAids = array_values($uniqueAids)
```

to reorder the keys.